# Safe to send member address to parent class during initialization?

Tags: c++

I need a **parent class to have a pointer to a child class' struct member**. Is it possible to solve this during initialization as shown below, or will the address to _foo not be available/be invalid?

```
struct Foo { int a; int b; }

class A {
public:
    A(void* fooHandle) : _fooHandle(fooHandle) {}

private:
    void* _fooHandle;
};

class B : public A {
public:
    B() : A(&_foo) {
        /* _foo initialized here */
    }
private:
    Foo _foo;
};
```

Is this code safe? I.e. will &_foo give a valid address? Of course I mean according to the standard, not whether it may work for some compilers.

Comment: so how do you construct `B` with `Foo`?

Comment: @codekaizer: by passing the address of the member as a constructor-initializer for the superclass.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is perfectly safe.

*EDIT (explanation)*: The storage for the object is allocated *before* any constructor is called. Objects occupy a region of storage that has one start and one end address. There may be gaps inbetween (padding). However for the whole lifetime of an object, all it's members are alive as well. When the constructors are called (eventually) all member objects part of the class the constructor of which is called, already live (by constructor I mean the part between `{…}`). This is why, if you need initialization before constructor execution you have to provide initializers. Members are initialized in the order as it appears in the class *and you'll get severe warnings if initializers appear in a different order*, so as long as you pass addresses to members, which went through initialization, you're within the lifetime of these members.

In the same way the lifetime of members ends only after all destructors were called.

Of course anything created with `new` and destroyed with `delete` has lifetimes that are not tied to class instance lifetimes, so you've to be careful with that.

However I wonder what the practical application of this is. Also I'd suggest to use a reference instead of a pointer to enforce passing a valid object and also making the constructor protected, so that it can be used only from child classes.

Comment: I wouldn't say perfectly safe, It would be unsafe to use that pointer in the base class constructor.

Comment: I'd say it safe as long as the base class (`A` here) only _stores_ the pointer and doesn't dereference it before the derived class (`B` here) is fully constructed.

Comment: @NathanOliver: did you mean it's unsafe to use that *instance* because it's not initialised yet? using the pointer should be fine

Comment: Good point regarding the protected constructor! Will do. This is a thread data container object that has a general implementation in a module called core, and a specific implementation in an OS-specific component. _foo is the native handle needed by the respective OS.

Comment: @AndriyTylychko Yes.  If the object has not been initialized in the derived class (which it has not when you are in the base class constructor) then its lifetime has not begun (only for non POD types) and dereferencing the pointers is UB.

Comment: @NathanOliver I agree with your points, but the alternative in my case would be to have the parent's void* pointer NULL and then rely on the child class setting it by itself.

Comment: *Members are initialized in the order as it appears in the initialization statement* This is false.  They are initialized in the order they are declared in the class and the base class(es) are always constructed first.

Comment: @LukasKalinski You're code as shown is OK.  I'm just saying it would be unsafe to dereference it in the body of `base::base()`.

Comment: @NathanOliver: Eh, right. However if you compile with `-Wall` you're going to get a ton of warnings if the order differs.

Comment: @datenwolf That's a good thing.  Too many people think they are constructed in the order they specify which can lead to some hard to find bugs.  It doesn't take much to put them in there proper order

Comment: Thank you for your elaborate answer, however, you cannot have a void reference, that's why I have a void pointer.

Comment: @LukasKalinski: The problem is that `A` can't do anything with a `void*` except give it back to `B`. And `B` already knows it points to `B::_foo`.

Comment: @MSalters The classes above are a simplification of two thread data container classes, one general, and another os-specific. I need a place to put os specific-data and then access it again through a general (OS agnostic) interface (thus void*). As there can only be one OS at a time, it is perfectly safe to assume that os data (represented by _foo above) will be of the right type.

Comment: @LukasKalinski: May I then suggest you use `uintptr_t` instead of `void*` for the SO specific handle. You can always safely cast between `uintptr_t` and `void*`, however casting arbitrary numbers (like, say OpenGL object names) to `void*` is begging for trouble.

Comment: @datenwolf Thank you for the tip. However, this is a very well-defined (embedded) environment and I don't see any problems with using void* in this particular case. Because like I said, the os specific data struct will always be the same in this case.